# Executing JS/jQ before images fully load

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, load

I have the following code, it calculates the width of a group of images in a horizontal gallery and applies it to a div so that they all fit:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
var totalwidth=0;

jQuery('#gallery img').each(function(){
totalwidth+= jQuery(this).width() + 15;
});

jQuery('#gallery').width(totalwidth+100);
});
```

The problem is, in a gallery of 100 images, no images are visible until all images are loaded. I don't know how to get around this, I want the images to load one after the other as they would on any other site.

Can it not calculate the width of all images, then apply that width to the div and load the images so the user can start browsing through them? Or does it need to fully load an image to obtain the width?

Thanks

Comment: The browser can only know the image size when it actually gets the image. How else would it know?

Comment: Why dont you put every image on fixed dimensional div so you will not have to face this problem

Comment: @Pointy, I don't know, that's why I'm asking. If an image can partially load and take up space as you watch it load, I don't see why 5 images for example, can't do the same. The width is there, why must they be fully loaded?

Comment: When there are a lot of images, what you're waiting for mostly is access to the self-limited number of connections. The browser will only try to fetch a few images at a time concurrently, like 4 or 6.  Once it starts getting the image data, there's only a very small window of time before it gets all of it. Before it even *asks* for the images, however, it has no clue.  You could of course use some build-time technique to pre-encode the image sizes into some JavaScript table or something, and make sure that's available early on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a bit more information on your html elements and exactly what you're trying to achieve it's difficult to give more advice but here's a first stab:

Javascript is client side scripting, essentially if your browser doesn't have the information, javascript doesn't. So, to get around that you could initially hide the images or their container and in your loop show them one by one as the function executes on each image - that way the calculation is done before the image is shown but the user feels like their getting a more instant response.

Comment: They are hidden, here is the site:

http://raycollinsphoto.com/published/

As you can see, the entire div will not load until all images are loaded, the problem is, I'm unsure of how to load one by one

Answer (score 0):

The browser knows the size of the image, when it's loaded.
You could put them in a hidden div, calculate the sizes and then display them one after another. Maybe this would work out for you.